# Ckeditor Balloon Toolbar showing at wrong position in firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5, ckeditor5-react

I am using Ckeditor balloon toolbar in my application. It works fine on Chrome. But on firefox, when I scroll the page, toolbar scrolls down and next time when I select the text it shows at wrong position.
In the below attached image, the balloon toolbar position is at wrong position.
Why is it so? It works fine on Chrome.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution for the question I posted above.
The issue was related to CSS. CSS in HTML tag i.e position: relative was conflicting with it.
After removing that, it worked fine.